# Make a Venn diagram of 5 bed files overlapped

Tags: r, bioinformatics, overlap, venn-diagram, bed

I have to compare the overlap or shared regions for 5 bed files and make a venn diagram of the overlapped regions.

I can use pybedtools but it's for 3 files max. Or I found  http://bioinformatics.psb.ugent.be/webtools/Venn/

It's look like a good tool but I have any idea how I can code my data for found the overlap.

Or maybe someone have an R package?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: There are many posts regarding Venn at biostars.org, for example this one: https://www.biostars.org/p/77362/

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can call what you are asking for a Venn diagram.
Suggest breaking the comparisons down to not more than three at a time and use  [area proportional ellipses](http://www.eulerdiagrams.org/eulerAPE/) to get a good enough approximation.
(It looks like the link you have is a similar tool)

Answer (score 0):

The link you included can do what you ask, you simply need to ask it to add more files to fit your set of five.

I just used the "list" version, and it did a fine job with diagramming five distinct points, However, it needs it listed as one data point entry per line.  I just used the alphabet as an example.

List one: (named it vowels)

a

e

i

o

u
 (remember one letter per line)

List two: cat

c

a

t

List three: cry

c

r

y

Now, click the add another list button....

List four: dog

d

o

g

List five: fish

f

i

s

h

Then calculate, and if you scroll to the bottom of the results, you get text specific mappings for each union, and the contents.

Names   total   elements
cat vowels  1   a

cat cry 1   c

dog vowels  1   o

fish vowels 1   i

cat 1   t

dog 2   d
        g

vowels  2   e
        u

fish    3   s
        h
        f

cry 2   r
        y

Comment: Thanks you for your response,
Yes it's work but with simply data.
Me, I have some files like this :
Chr   Start                  End
1 143274104 143274337 
Y 10001 10038 
Y 12798 12817 

And I have 5 files with somethink like 40.000 lines. And I have to check the overlap between the files and make it at the intersection of circle.
So I don't know how I can do for this.

Thanks you